# How can I parse and echo CGI query string parameters?

Tags: perl, cgi

I would like to execute a command on the server by using the system request parameters in the URL. I am running the server.

In the browser ->> `//localhost:9009/?comd` which is displaying the list of files in the directory as i placed in the code

```
if (/comd/i )        { print  $client `dir`;      }
```

How I can parse the request parameters? For example:

`http://localhost:9009/?comd&user=kkc&mail=kkc@kkc.com`

I would like to return -->> `hello user please confirm your email kkc@kkc.com`

How can I parse the request parameters in the url?

Answer (score 4):

```
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new();

my $user = $cgi->param( "user" );
my $mail = $cgi->param( "mail" );

print( "Hello $user please confirm your email $mail\n" );
```

Comment: You're not returning a Content-Type header and are not validating the input a user might send. Not validating the input is asking for problems.

Comment: mmm, yummy XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: the question is about how to parse the query string, not how to prevent hacking attemps. If we had to write every time for every question all the code needed to prevent attacks, this website would be useless.

Comment: @Htbaa I worked with a contractor who claimed, on his CV, to be the "subject matter expert" in Perl at a large city bank in London. He had never heard of Taint Mode. If you were serious about security I'd have expected your first comment to have mentioned Taint Mode. However I'm sure you recognise that I answered the question asked succinctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$|++;                              # auto flush output

use CGI;                           # module that simplifies grabbing parameters from query string
use HTML::Entities;                # for character encoding
use strict;                        # to make sure your Perl code is well formed

print qq{Content-type: text/html\n\n};  # http header b/c outputting to browser

   main();                         # calling the function

   sub main{
      my $cgi    = new CGI;        # store all the cgi variables
      # the following stores all the query string variables into a hash
      #   this is unique because you might have multiple query string values for
      #   for a variable. 
      #   (eg http://localhost/?email=a@b.com&email=b@c.com&email=c@d.com )
      my %params = map { $_ => HTML::Entities::encode(join("; ", split("\0", $cgi->Vars->{$_}))) } $cgi->param;

      #Input: http://localhost:9009/?comd&user=kkc&mail=kkc@kkc.com
      #Output: Hello kcc please confirm your email kkc@kkc.com

      print <<HTML;
      <html>
         <head>
            <style type="text/css">.bold{font-weight:bold}</style>
         </head>
         <body>
            Hello <span class="bold">$params{user}</span> please confirm your email <span class="bold">$params{mail}</span>
         </body>
      </html>
HTML

      return 1;
   }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: See comments about XSS on the answer given 4 months ago.

Comment: You're downvoting for that?  This is an example and not meant to be the most secure thing ever.  Your comment is considered noise.

Comment: Added some encoding, just to get around your XSS nonsense.

Comment: Clearly commented codes answer the question of "query string", it deserve up vote.

Answer (score 2):

```
use CGI;
use HTML::Template;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $html = qq{
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head><title>Confirmation</title></head>
    <body><p>Hello <TMPL_VAR USER ESCAPE=HTML>. 
    Please confirm your email <TMPL_VAR MAIL ESCAPE=HTML></p></body>
    </html>
};

my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(scalarref => \$html, associate => $cgi);
print $cgi->header('text/html'), $tmpl->output;
```